# LINQ function translation problem

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a problem with translation my function when i try to select data from table. So, now i have about 130000 rows with "words" and they were written on my language- russian:

привет, пока, москва.

But i need to translate this words on english and find them in database with their english transcription:

привет = privet, пока = poka, москва = moskva.

I just make Replace ('п' -> 'p', 'т' -> 't').

But when i'm tring to execute extension method on LINQ table property, i have an exception, and i know it. So, how could i use function on property in

`.Where(t=> FunctionReplaceName(t.Name)`) ?

Thx.

```
public static string Translate(this string stringToTranslate)
{
    string[] kirArray = { "А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ё", "Ж", "З", "И", "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ы", "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я", ",", ".", " ", "(", ")" };
    string[] latArray = { "A", "B", "V", "G", "D", "E", "JO", "ZH", "Z", "I", "IJ", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "U", "F", "H", "TZ", "CH", "SH", "SH", "", "JY", "", "JE", "JU", "JA", "", "", "-", "", "" };
    stringToTranslate = stringToTranslate.ToUpper();

    for (int i = 0; i < kirArray.Length; i++)
        if (stringToTranslate.IndexOf(kirArray[i]) != -1)
            stringToTranslate = stringToTranslate.Replace(kirArray[i], latArray[i]);

    return stringToTranslate.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is. Are you saying that Translate() throws and you need help with that?

Comment: I also see a couple of problems in Translate(). First, it looks like you assume an instance of kirArray could only appear once in the stringToTranslate. But it also looks like you'd have infinite loops if you checked each element - "A" maps to "A"?

Comment: In my database, i have russian values in fields. But in url i have english values, and i cant translate english -> russian, so i need to translate russian->english, just to make 33 replace 'A'->'А', 'Б'->'В', and then compare result. My problem that i try to make action with database values, and LINQ give me exception

Answer (score 1):

First, your where predicate is invalid:

```
 .Where(t=> FunctionReplaceName(t.Name))
```

That is not a valid where clause.  It needs to return a bool.  Do you actually have something like this?

```
.Where(t=> FunctionReplaceName(t.Name) == inputName)
```

If so, you are doing it backwards -- you are (syntactically) trying to convert the value in the DB using your function.  Instead you should do as you were trying, `"to translate this words on english and find them in database with their english transcription."` You should have:

```
.Where(t=> t.Name == FunctionReplaceName(inputName))
```

I *think* that should work, but possibly sql translation may still barf on your function call, in which case you should call your function on the value (`inputName`) and store it in a string variable before calling `Where`.

Comment: I cant translate input value, and this is the problem. I have to translate value in database and then compare with input.

Comment: @user, then you're out of luck in terms of writing it in C# -- the work will have to be done on the DB, and there's no way your C# logic can be run there in this way.  You can write a user-defined function in TSQL and use that.  But can you explain why you can't translate the input value?  You said it's stored in the db as latin characters, and your function converts cyrillic characters to latin.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. In russian i have "привет, москва- это я", but when i translate this on english, i have "privet-moskva-eto-ja". I make "," and other symbols translating, bcz they are using in URL- "/word/privet-moskva-eto-ja", so, "privet-moskva-eto-ja" - i cant translate back to russian.

Comment: @user, In that case, you really are going to have to write this translation logic directly in T-SQL as a user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ-to-SQL doesn't know how to translate `FunctionReplaceName` to SQL, so it's giving you an error.

Try replacing it with this:

```
.ToList().Where(t=> FunctionReplaceName(t.Name));
```

Note that this will pull everything into memory from the database, so apply your other `.Where` clauses *before* this.

Comment: Yeap, i wrote that i have about 130000 rows in database, and this is not solution

Comment: @user568262: Then could you show us the function, and where it is used, so we could help you out a bit more?